# Credulity versus Complacency in "The __ of the king in running the country..."?

Tags: questions, exam-questions

> The __ of the king in running the country motivated the parliamentarians to usurp the throne & execute him; hence Oliver Cromwell was named Lord Protector of the realm.

The sentence came in fill in the blanks. The options are--
a. Credulity
b. Complacency

I chose "credulity" as the answer because a king can be dethroned by his parliamentarians when he is gullible, has blind faith, over trustfulness, unworldliness,lack of experience, ignorance etc. That's when the parliamentarians dare go against the king. N those are exactly what credulity mean.

On the other hand, complacency means self satisfaction, laziness and unwilling to work.

Comparing the meanings I feel it'll be credulity. Because a king can't be dethroned just because he is too self satisfied and lazy. This word doesn't mean the king isn't intelligent enough to handle the parliamentarians. But credulity does mean gullible and that is a great opportunity to dare go against the king. As the king is ignorant, synonym of credulity, so the parliamentarians wanted to take the opportunity.

PLEASE explain in details of whatever you think is correct. I'm having real troubles with the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The right answer here is complacency with the meaning of growing complacent and with complacent having the meaning of:

> feeling so satisfied with your own abilities or situation that you feel you do not need to try any harder.

In effect, the king not trying any harder enabled his dethroning and demise. Had he been less certain of his position of power and superiority he’d been more vigilant and could have prevented the parliamentarians to move against him.

As opposed to that, credulity is a little bit forced. Yes, a gullible king can cause his befall but it doesn’t really fit too well on the overall sentence. The king grew careless and overconfident (complacent) and that cause his downfall.

Credulity here will really make no sense to me in the context of the phrase as having a tendency to believe in people or stories doesn’t really make you less vigilant or on guard or vulnerable. Not necessarily anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Credulity *could* be a reason why a king would be challenged, but there is no evidence for it in the sentence.

There *is* evidence, however, that the king was challenged because of his complacency because the king is *contrasted* with the parliamentarians.  And what is known about the parliamentarians?

> The __ of the king in running the country ***motivated*** the parliamentarians to usurp the throne...

And to be "complacent" is the opposite of being "motivated."